# Exception when trying to extract version from pom.xml

Tags: java

I am trying to read my pom.xml to get the version number but keep getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/util/xml/pull/XmlPullParserException
        at com.wenzey.core.utils.Log.sendStartupMessage(Log.java:5)
        at com.wenzey.core.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 2 more
```

I find this strange, as I've checked my jar and the pom.xml definitely exists:

[image]

My code is as follows, it works fine in dev mode but not after the package has been built:

**VersionProvider class**

```
class VersionProvider {
    static String getVersion() throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        MavenXpp3Reader reader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
        Model model;
        String VERSION_NUMBER;
        if ((new File("pom.xml")).exists()) {
            model = reader.read(new FileReader("pom.xml"));
            VERSION_NUMBER = model.getVersion();
        } else {
            model = reader.read(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            VersionProvider.class.getResourceAsStream(
                                    "/META-INF/maven/com.wenzey/wenzey-core/pom.xml"
                            )
                    )
            );
            VERSION_NUMBER = model.getVersion();
        }
        return VERSION_NUMBER;
    }
}
```

**Main class**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        Log.sendStartupMessage();
    }
}
```

**Log class**

```
public class Log {
    public static void sendStartupMessage() throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        String versionNumber = VersionProvider.getVersion();
        System.out.print(":: wenzey ((v." + versionNumber + ")) ::");
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.wenzey</groupId>
    <artifactId>wenzey-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.wenzey.core.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Read the exception. It doesn't complain about the absence of pom.xml. It complais about the absence of the class org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException in your classpath.

Comment: Thanks. How do I add it to my classpath?